# Question about potential additives to a very relative Covid 19 m R N A patent (i.e. radio active Ions: Iodine 125 or 131, Strontium 89, cesium, etc.)

Tags: nuclear-physics, physical-chemistry, biophysics, radioactivity, isotopes

I am a genuinely concerned citizen with barely any scientific background concerning radioactive isotopes. However, I have a question about items listed in an mRNA 1273 patent on Moderna's website.

While looking over one of the mRNA patents, I found this information could be a potential cause for concern. I've emailed a few experts about this with no response as I'm sure they are busy or think I'm too out there. I need to get this off my chest for my sanity, and I either need to know if it is a cause for public concern, or I need someone to debunk the risks of it so I can move on with my life. Are there safe levels of these isotopes for healthy individuals of all populations, or is any amount a public health risks? Am I crazy, and looking too much into this? From what I have read up on Radiation Emergencies, many of these are ions are on the "isotopes of concern" lists, especially if they are ingested internally.

The highlighted parts are the parts that made me go, hm? Especially "Radioactive ions include, but are not limited to iodine (e.g., iodine 125 or iodine 131), strontium 89, phosphorus, palladium, cesium, iridium, phosphate, colbalt, yttrium 90, samarium 153, and praseodymium."
[image]

I know now that treatments like Radio Iodine 131 Therapy for thyroid cancer can be intense. People have to carry around nuclear medicine cards saying they could be radioactive for up to 3 months. If this were plausible, it shouldn't be taken lightly, especially around children and pregnant women, right? This info differs from the ingredients listed on other documents. Feel free to google Moderna Patents mRNA-1273 and click on 10,442,756 to see the whole document.

Many of the symptoms people are experiencing recently with SARS-CoV-2 seem to be progressing to those similar to internal and external radiation sickness. Now many children are being affected way more than before the vaccine roll out. I am not a Covid denier; I'm just noticing that things have taken an interesting turn on various fronts since the vaccine role out (and the variants).

What if these radioactive ions (and potentially others) were in these therapeutic vaccines? How would that affect the current situation with this pandemic? Looking at this patent clearly shows that it is not entirely impossible, but please correct me if I'm wrong. How I even went down the rabbit hole on any of this was deciding WHICH vaccine to get. After following the money, I decided to wait for the science to reveal itself.

Discovering this information in the mRNA-1273 PatentNo.: US 10,442,756B2 a few weeks back has brought me to a point where I need answers without making a complete "conspiracy theory" fool of myself. With each passing day, I feel the urge to bring this to someones attention. I brought it up to my friend who's a new nurse and recently graduated from nursing school, and her response was, "Yeah but isn't that all medicine in general?" moral of the story: I was reading too much into it, and also wasn't a person that was qualified to even develop my own thought processes from the information I was seeing. May be true, but I think there's a difference between cancer treatment and one size fits all medicine. Correct?

So what do people with this area of expertise think? These patents are all very detailed and reference each other, yet are also extremely vague at the same time with no mention of the types for some of the radioactive ions, which could make a world of difference.

Link to the patent: https://www.modernatx.com/sites/default/files/US10442756.pdf

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that mRNA-1273 patents are protected by patent laws, so which kinds and how much of these ions seem to be potentially protected under trade secret laws. As far as I know, with looking into their SEC filings, the mRNA-1273 vaccine is not one of Moderna's cancer vaccines, so why include that information in the mRNA-1273 patent if it doesn't apply? Everything is telling me it could potentially apply to these experimental vaccines. This mRNA-1273 patent is for the Moderna technology, and I haven't looked into the Bio N tech one yet. It feels like everyone is looking at studies (as am I), but not many people talk about the patents.

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1682852/000168285220000017/mrna-20200630.htm

If you are following the link to the patent, the information is located in section 106. Any answers are much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics

Comment: You have confused what goes into a cytotoxic compound (which can contain isotopes) and what goes into a Covid vaccine, which is mainly mRNA.

Comment: This patent is not about the covid vaccine, it is about ways that therapeutic agents can be delivered. Since, as you say, radioisotopes can be used to treat cancer, the patent covers using their *nanoparticle* delivery system to deliver radioisotopes as well as every other type of therapeutic agent they could think of. There is no relation to the covid vaccine and there are no radioisotopes in covid vaccines.

Comment: I feel this question should be moved to another site, maybe [biology.se] or [skeptics.se]?

Answer (score 3):

This question should be closed since it has a little to do with physics. But something should be said here, due to the danger of misinformation.

---

There seems to be confusion. From what I can tell, the citation you have provided speaks about "*Compounds and Compositions For
Intracellular Delivery of
Therapeutic Agents*" and when referring to "some embodiments", they mean those that are used for *various* therapies and not just Covid vaccination. The radioactive isotopes you are referring to are in the class of chemotherapy drugs and by design need to be destructive to *cancer* cells. This does not mean that these ingredients are in a Covid vaccine. Indeed what would be the point?
Cytotoxic agents are used to destroy cancer cells through various mechanisms, and one being the carrier of radioisotopes that specifically target cancer cells.

The Covid vaccine uses mRNA or [messenger RNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messenger_RNA) and the RNA stands for *Ribonucleic Acid* and is *not* an acronym for anything "Radioactive".
Messenger RNA is a single-stranded molecule of RNA corresponding to a genetic sequence allowing the process of gene copying from DNA.

Messenger RNA vaccines are relatively new in the protection against infectious diseases. Earlier vaccines were used to trigger immune responses by introducing a weak (or even deactivated) pathogen into the human body. mRNA vaccines instead produce an immune response by causing our cells to form a protein which triggers this response (the production of antibodies) which protects us from the pathogen (virus) if it enters our body.

The (Moderna) Covid vaccine [contains](https://www.fda.gov/media/144638/download#page=2):
Messenger ribonucleic acid (mRNA), lipids (SM-102, polyethylene glycol [PEG] 2000
dimyristoyl glycerol [DMG], cholesterol, and 1,2-distearoyl-sn-glycero-3-phosphocholine [DSPC]),
tromethamine,tromethamine hydrochloride, acetic acid, sodium acetate trihydrate, and sucrose.

No radioactive substances at all. Your assertion is as valid as other Covid conspiracies. Another similar question asked on this site is about the ability to [magnetize a human](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665480/could-you-make-someone-magnetic-without-killing-them/665484#665484) also by the administering of a vaccine, but that had more to do with physics than this one.